# Website breaks when Firebug is enabled

Tags: javascript, html, import, firebug

I use Firebug to do most of my web debugging.  In one of the web applications I'm working on, the application breaks when Firebug is enabled; it seems that some JS resources (mainly jQuery) aren't being loaded.  When I disable Firebug, the site works great.  Any ideas on how Firebug might be interfering with how the site runs, and what can be done to fix it?

Comment: check console output and see if there any errors.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the site in Chrome?

Comment: Did you try uninstalling firebug and installing the newest version?

Comment: Could you tell us: Which is the Firebug version you use? What website (url) you develop?